# Getting common values from entries of a map in an efficient way

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, hashmap, java-stream

Suppose there is map as show below:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> myMap =     
     {   
        k1: [ v1, v2, v3, v3],  
        k2: [ v1, v2],  
        k3: [ v1, v2, v6, v7]
      }
```

I want to find values which are common for all the keys.

```
 List<String> commonValues = {v1,v2}
```

I want to understand the efficient way of doing it using java 8. I am able to achieve the same using for loops in java 5, but I am sure Java 8 is having better ways of doing it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `k1` maps to multiple items?

Comment: @sleepToken thank you for pointing out, I corrected the data

Comment: Dont use static initialization, recommended. Moreover i dont think your initialisation is even correct.

Comment: @VishwaRatna I was just intending to show how the map is, wasn't initializing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```java
List<String> commonValues = myMap.values().stream()
    .reduce((a, b) -> {
        a.retainAll(b);
        return a;
    })
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

[From the doc of `retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-):

> Retains only the elements in this collection that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this collection all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.

In case you're working with multiple threads or collections which are immutable:

```java
List<String> commonValues = myMap.values().stream()
    .reduce((a, b) -> {
        List<String> c = new ArrayList<>(a);
        c.retainAll(b);
        return c;
    })
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Though this solution creates a new copy every iteration.

Another way would be somewhat more hacky:

```
List<String> commonValues = myMap.values().stream()
    .reduce(null, (a, b) -> {
        if(a == null) return new ArrayList<>(b);
        a.retainAll(b);
        return a;
    });
```

But this time, `commonValues` may be `null`, so you'd have to check for that

Comment: I believe this raises an `UnsupportedOperationException` for the example data OP provided.

Comment: @sleepToken but only if the underlying `list` is immutable

Comment: agreed after your edit - am I wrong for thinking that a HashMap in java is mutable?

Comment: @sleepToken , `Arrays.asList() `, will surely be immutable.

Comment: @sleepToken since the OP didn’t provide valid Java code, we don’t know which actual type the collections will have. But using reduction with a function which modifies the input is broken anyway. Especially with the Stream API, which requires the function to be associative, so it doesn’t even allow to predict, which of the input collections will end up modified, if they support modifications…